How to Implement Jitsi for Audio/Video Calls with WhatsApp/Skype-Like Features?
I'm currently working on a project that requires implementing a chat feature similar to WhatsApp or Skype, with the ability to make audio and video calls. Our team initially considered using Jitsi, but we found that it operates more like Google Meet, where users share a link for meetings. Is there a way to leverage Jitsi to create audio/video call functionality akin to WhatsApp or Skype, where users can initiate calls directly within the chat interface?
Details:

Our project aims to incorporate audio and video call capabilities seamlessly within a chat application.
We are exploring the possibility of utilizing Jitsi for this purpose but are open to alternative solutions if they better align with our requirements.
Any insights, resources, or experiences related to integrating Jitsi or similar technologies for this use case would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Context:

Our technology stack primarily revolves around Flutter and React Native for cross-platform mobile application development.
We prioritize simplicity, scalability, and user experience in our development approach.

We are wondering how to use Jitsi to make phone calls to users using technologies like Flutter or React Native.
